# Single lagged PACF spike: Why select MA term in model and not AR term?

Tags: self-study, autocorrelation, model

I'm trying to understand the specific choice of model in an example in the book "Applied Econometric Time Series" by Enders, chapter 2 ("Stationary time-series models"), section 7 ("Sample autocorrelations of stationary series -- Estimation of an AR(1) Model", around page 90 in my copy).

In this section the sample ACF and PACF of a time series are presented (figure 2.3, top two panels). The ACF is relatively rapidly and steadily decaying, and the PACF has a large spike at lag 1. Larger lags in the PACF are not significant (against sample variance of PACF $T^{-1}$), except for a significant spike at lag 12.

To me, this seems to be consistent with an AR(1) process, except for the lag 12 in the PACF, which indicates a seasonality effect. So far so good.

Now, Enders selects and comparatively assesses two models:

- Model 1. An AR(1) model: $y_t = a_1 y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$
- Model 2. An AR(1) model with added moving-average term at lag 12: $y_t = a_1 y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t + \beta_{12} \epsilon_{t-12}$

**My questions:**

- Given that the spike at lag 12 is in the PACF, not in the ACF, shouldn't the PACF spike at lag 12 be accounted for with an *autoregressive* term at lag 12, i.e., model 3: $y_t = a_1 y_{t-1} + a_{12} y_{t-12} + \epsilon_t$? Can you please explain why model 2 would be preferred over model 3 with the ACF/PACF pattern described above?
- I always thought spikes in the ACF can be explained by forcing (moving average) terms $\beta_j \epsilon_{t-j}$, and spikes in the PACF with autoregressive terms $a_j y_{t-j}$. Is this notion false?

Comment: At the first glance, your logic seems fine...